# Google Maps Javascript v3: checkboc for markers won t work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, google-maps-markers

Hi there and greetings to all,

I am trying to have a checkbox for my markers categories on my map (google maps api v3)
I want to make something similar like this example
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

I copied the source of this example and pasted it in my texteditor so that i could change it and it won' t work. I thought that this was due to the external file

so i copied this and saved it in a folder named script. It won t work again!

Has anyone else went through this before? My javascript and programming skills are very bad. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem most likely is that you are not providing the xml file with the marker categories. In the source code of the example the categories.xml file is referenced locally ... download the file from : http://www.geocodezip.com/categories.xml to the same directory as your webpage file and it should work - it works for me. 
One more thing, in 8th line of the html file you need to also change the address of the XML loading script to http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/downloadxml.js or have it locally saved

K